# Python - Small Change to a Huge File

Tags: python

This is a theoretical question as I don't have an actual problem, but I got to wondering ...

If I had a *huge* file, say many gigs long and I wanted to change a single byte and I knew the offset of that byte, how could I do this efficiently? Is there a way to do this without rewriting the entire file and only writing the single byte?

I'm not seeing anything in the Python *file* api that would let me write to a particular offset in a file.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek You set the cursor position using seek(), then write(), then flush() to save changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you don't need to *insert* or *delete* bytes, you can open the file in `"r+"` mode, use the [`seek`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) method to position the file object at the byte to change, and write out one byte.

It may be more efficient to use the lower-level [`os.open`, `os.lseek`, `os.read`, and `os.write`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.lseek) operations, which do not do any application-level buffering.

If you *do* need to insert or delete bytes, sorry, you're out of luck: there is no way to do that without rewriting the entire file (from the point of the first insertion or deletion).  This is a limitation of the POSIX (and AFAIK also Windows) low-level file APIs, not of Python specifically.

Comment: Surely you only need to write the file from the edit point, not the entire file?

Comment: Beautiful answer. Thanks very much! But did you mean rewriting "from the point of the first change" rather than the entire file? I'm just referencing your comment from down below.

Comment: Yes, both of you are correct, I was simplifying a little.  (The standard technique for replacing a file *atomically* involves making a full copy, so often people just do that anyway.)

Comment: Really? What if I have 5 gb file and 1gb ram? That's common for logs on shared hosts and the like or modifying video/audio streams on a laptop. You're not going to load things into memory. You can't. You write the changes to disk.

Answer (score 2):

You can seek() to a position and write a single byte. It will overwrite what's there, rather than inserting.

Comment: Ah, ok, related to this, what if I wanted to insert? In each case (insert/change) is the entire file rewritten or is just a single byte written? Or does this depend only on the fs?

Comment: Neither Unix (incl. OSX) nor Windows (AFAIK) provides system calls to insert or delete bytes from a large file without rewriting the entire file from the point of the first change.

Answer (score 2):

Seek to that position in the file and write a single byte. File objects in Python have a seek method that takes in an integer offset from some constant:

```
seek(offset[, whence])
```

The whence argument is optional and defaults to 0 (absolute file positioning); other values are 1 (seek relative to the current position) and 2 (seek relative to the file's end).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial for what might want to do: http://diveintopython3.ep.io/files.html#read

'seek'  is the method to find the byte you want. The above link talks about cautions you need to take